# Can I use Present simple and Present Perfect in the same sentence?

Tags: present-tense, present-simple

> No one **claims** to be able to cure a genetic disease, but there **have been** some improvements.

Is the use of present simple and present perfect in the same sentence correct?

Comment: Yes. Of course! "The wheels **turn** easily when they **have been** oiled." "It **is** raining now but it **has been** a beautiful day." "I **have been** driving since I was twenty, but these days I **walk** everywhere." "She **says** you **have been** there."

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is perfectly valid. You can use mutplies types of tenses in an expression, if they make sense.

Your sentence has two components,

1: There have been improvements in research of genetic disease.(Present Perfect)

2: No one claims to have cure of genetic disease.(Simple present).